# Can't capture Android Listview checkbox state

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

Try as I might, I simply can't detect the true/false (checked/unchecked) state of my Listview checkboxes. I'm building these on the fly and that may be part of the problem.

My code:

1. building the listview with checkboxes:

   ```
           ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(                
    activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, results);
   setListAdapter(adapter);
   for (int i = 0; i < activity.getListAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                       activity.getListView().setItemChecked(i, true); //doesn't work BTW
   ```

   }
2. capturing the checkbox click event: //never shows checked, even when it is

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View view, int position, long id) {     
       super.onListItemClick(lv, view, position, id);
       CheckedTextView checkBox = (CheckedTextView)this.activity.getListView().getAdapter().getView(position, view, null);
   ```

many thanks

Max

Comment: have you tried setting this, `listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);` exact below your `setListAdapter(adapter);`.

Comment: Well, that worked for setting the checkboxes so thanks for that. I am still unable to pick up the correct state on the submit though - shows false. I realized I did not post the code from my button click. here it is (below):

Comment: public void onClick(View v) { 
//search for list view items clicked to unfollow
LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.listLayout);      
for (int i = 0; i < activity.getListAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)activity.getListAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
} //always shows false - even when they are checked
}});

Answer (score 0):

So this is what I came up with:

In my submit logic I was not able to pick up the checkBox state so I track it in onItemClick

unfollowerState is an array of booleans I use to keep track of checked state ... I pick it up on submit

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView lv, View view, int position, long id) {     
    super.onListItemClick(lv, view, position, id);
    CheckedTextView checkBox = (CheckedTextView) view; //get the UI checkBox
    Log.i(LOG_TAG, ".onListItemClick" + checkBox.getText() + " " + checkBox.isChecked());
    unfollowerState[position-1]=checkBox.isChecked();  //record the check state
}
```